# What is the plane of a concave or convex mirror?

Tags: reflection, geometric-optics

What is the plane of a concave or convex mirror? Is it along its principal axis or its area? I am convinced that the plane should be along the area of mirror but i am not sure about it. I tried to find it in books but didn't got any answer. Some books have questions like a point object is moving in a circle in a perpendicular plane to the mirror so find radius of image. Such questions are confusing to solve if we don't know where would be the plane of mirror.

Comment: Actually it has infinite planes, in reailty the mirror will be 3D object, now at each point on reflecting side you can think of best fitting tanget plane (similar to tangent line). Now this plane has normal direction, that is the normal you take for snells law

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such particular definition for *plane of mirror*, in fact this term is very ambiguous since spherical mirrors aren't planar. "Plane of mirror" - these words are just used to express questions (like plane of paper or plane of the *plane* mirror). Physics doesn't defines that ***this particular*** plane is called the "plane of mirror".

In your question-

> Some books have questions like a point object is moving in a circle in a perpendicular plane to the mirror so find radius of image.

The plane of motion of the point object is perpendicular to the **Principle Axis** of the mirror.
Generally, we take principle axis of the mirror as our reference  for all calculations and observations.